# php url segment based routing: looping over url segments instead of array of routes

Tags: php, routes

I have a routes class that loops over url segments and looks up controller/action from a routes array, instead  the other way around. The idea is the max number of loops is usually no more than 3 no matter how many routes there are.

Is there an established framework or class that does this?  The code in  my class is getting a little on the messy side.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some to get you started:

http://codeigniter.com/

http://framework.zend.com/

http://kohanaframework.org/

http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/

Comment: None of these use a segment looping technique. CI, Zend, and Kohanna loop over a routes array, and fat free uses an anonymous functions

Comment: It doesn't have to, but if you have 50 defined routes, that's an average of 25 loops to a get route. With my system of looping though url segments, it's never more than 3 loops, and most of the the time just 1 or 2 loops.

Comment: With it being so awesome I am there are plenty of frameworks that support this system. I know of none, obviously.